# OpenWRT port redirection

Tags: iptables, port, redirection, openwrt

I have an OpenWRT router.

What I need to achieve is a port redirection within my LAN zone. What I mean is, every time I hit local address on port 40413 it should to be redirected to 192.168.1.111:443

For example. if I put in browser:
https://192.168.1.111:40443
it should point to 192.168.1.111:443
That's pretty easy with plain iptable rule:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i br-lan -p tcp --dport 40443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 443
```

I tried to it into /etc/firewall.user but no effect...

I also tried with rule main firewall config:
/etc/config/firewall

```
config redirect
   option name 'owncloud_internal'
   option src 'lan'
   option proto 'tcp'
   option src_dport '40443'
   option dest_ip '192.168.1.111'
   option dest_port '443'
   option target 'DNAT'
   option dest 'lan'
```

But still no effect.

Can someone explain how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. This is not possible to archive using router settings because communication does not go throught routing, so it is not possible to manipulate it that way. Probably i should setup proxy, but in my case it was easier to reconfigure https server to listen on 40443 port.